# Array even & odd sorting

Tags: java

I have an array where I have some numbers. Now I want to sort even numbers in a separate array and odd numbers in a separate. Is there any API to do that? I tried like this

```
int[] array_sort={5,12,3,21,8,7,19,102,201};
int [] even_sort;
int i;
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{

if(array_sort[i]%2==0)
{
     even_sort=Arrays.sort(array_sort[i]);//error in sort
        
System.out.println(even_sort);
}
}
```

Comment: What did you try? create two different arrays with odd numbers and even numbers,  sort two arrays. There is an overhead on space - Are you talking about a million numbers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Plain and simple.

```
int[] array_sort = {5, 12, 3, 21, 8, 7, 19, 102, 201 };

List<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i : array_sort) {
    if ((i & 1) == 1) {
        odd.add(i);
    } else {
        even.add(i);
    }
}
Collections.sort(odd);
Collections.sort(even);
System.out.println("Odd:" + odd);
System.out.println("Even:" + even);
```

Comment: Really Plain and simple. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Your question as stated doesn't make sense, and neither does the code.  So I'm guessing that you want to separate the elements of an array into two arrays, one containing odds and the other evens.  If so, do it like this:

```
int[] input = {5, 12, 3, 21, 8, 7, 19, 102, 201};
List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i : input) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        evens.add(i);
    } else {
        odds.add(i);
    }
}
```

You can then convert a list of Integer to a sorted array if int as follows:

```
List<Integer> list ...
int[] array = new int[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = list.get(i);
}
Arrays.sort(array);
```

or if a sorted `List<Integer>` is what you need, just do this:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple to do this using Guava.

- Use [`Ints.asList`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29) to create a `List<Integer>` live view of an `int[]`
- Define a `Function<Integer,Boolean> isOdd`
- Use `Ordering` that compares `onResultOf(isOdd)`, naturally (i.e. `false` first, then `true`)
- If necessary, `compound` that with an `Ordering.natural()`

Here's the snippet:

```
    int[] nums = {5,12,3,21,8,7,19,102,201};
    Function<Integer,Boolean> isOdd = new Function<Integer,Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(Integer i) {
            return (i & 1) == 1;
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(
        Ints.asList(nums),
        Ordering.natural().onResultOf(isOdd)
            .compound(Ordering.natural())
    );
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    // [8, 12, 102, 3, 5, 7, 19, 21, 201]
```

Note that all the even numbers show up first, then all the odd numbers. Within each group, the numbers are sorted naturally.

#### External links

- [polygenelubricants.com - Writing more elegant comparison logic with Guava's Ordering](http://www.polygenelubricants.com/2010/10/elegant-comparison-logic-with-guava.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are some things to know first :

- You must initialize an array before using it. For example `int[] even_sort = new int[3];`
- In java arrays have a static size. That means that you won't be able to add as many elements as you want. You have to choose a size before. You should take a look at Java Collections, it's a good way to get rid of this "rule" the java way.
- The `Arrays.sort()` method apply on arrays only. Here `array_sort[i]` is an `int`
- `Arrays.sort()` sorts an array but doesn't return anything.

---

If you really want to use arrays (but you shouldn't) you can do something like this to resize one :

```
int[] even_sort = new int[3]{1, 2, 3};
int[] temp = new int[4];
System.arraycopy(even_sort, 0, temp, 0, even_sort.length);
even_sort = temp;
even_sort[3] = 4;
```

---

Another way would be creating an utility method which uses reflection to create the new array :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public Object resizeArray(Object originalArray, int newSize){
    int originalSize = Array.getLength(originalArray);
    Class arrayType = originalArray.getClass().getComponentType();
    Object newArray = Array.newInstance(arrayType, newSize);
    System.arraycopy(originalArray, 0, newArray, 0, Math.min(originalSize, newSize));
    return newArray;
}
```

---

So if you still want to use array for some reasons (but you still shouldn't) here is a code to filter, resize and sort your array.

```
int[] arrayToFilterAndSort = {5, 12, 3, 21, 8, 7, 19, 102, 201};
int[] sortedEvens = new int[0];
for(int current : arrayToFilterAndSort){
    if((current & 1) == 1){
        sortedEvens = resizeArray(sortedEvens, sortedEvens.length + 1);
        sortedEvens[sortedEvens.length - 1] = current;
    }
}
Arrays.sort(sortedEvens);
```

---

**Resources :**

- [oracle.com - Arrays tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [oracle.com - Collections tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)
- [javadoc - `Arrays.sort()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.java.util.collection;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Given n random numbers. Move all even numbers on left hand side and odd numbers on right hand side and 
 * then sort the even numbers in increasing order and odd numbers in decreasing order For example, 
 * i/p : 3 6 9 2 4 10 34 21 5 
 * o/p: 2 4 6 10 34 3 5 9 21
 * @author vsinha
 *
 */
public class EvenOddSorting {

    public static void eventOddSort(int[] arr) {
        int i =0;
        int j =arr.length-1;
        while(i<j) {
            if(isEven(arr[i]) && isOdd(arr[j])) {
                i++;
                j--;
            } else if(!isEven(arr[i]) && !isOdd(arr[j])) {
                swap(i,j,arr);
            } else if(isEven(arr[i])){
                i++;
            } else{
                j--;
            }

        }   
        display(arr);
        // even number sorting
        Arrays.sort(arr,0,i);
        Arrays.sort(arr,i,arr.length);
        // odd number sorting
        display(arr);

    }

    public static void display(int[] arr) {
        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int val:arr){
            System.out.print(val +"  ");
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int pos1, int pos2, int[] arr) {
        int temp = arr[pos1];
        arr[pos1]= arr[pos2];
        arr[pos2]= temp;
    }

    public static boolean isOdd(int i) {
        return (i & 1) != 0;
    }
    public static boolean isEven(int i) {
        return (i & 1) == 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[]={3, 6, 9 ,2, 4, 10, 34, 21, 5};
        eventOddSort(arr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[20] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
cout << "The Even no are : \n";
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // for start for only i....(even nos)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << i;
        cout << " ";
    }
}
cout << "\nThe Odd no are : \n";
for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) // for start for only j....(odd nos)
{
    if (j % 2 != 0)
    {
        cout << j;
        cout << " ";
    }`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
package srikanth dukuntla;

public class ArrangingArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j=0;
        int []array={1,2,3,5,4,55,32,0};
        System.out.println(array.length);
        int n=array.length/2;
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){

            if(array[i]%2!=0){
                j=1;

                int temp=array[array.length-j];
            if(temp % 2!=0){

                while((array[array.length-(j+1)]%2!=0) && (array.length-(j+1)>n)){
                        j++;
                }
                    int temp2=array[array.length-(j+1)];
                     array[array.length-(j+1)] =array[i];
                      array[i]=temp2;

                }else // inner if
                {
                 array[array.length-j] =array[i];
                  array[i]=temp;
                }

            }else //main if
            {
                //nothing needed

            }

        }

        for(int k=0;k<array.length;k++) {
            System.out.print(" "+ array[k]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Also won't compile due to invalid package name.

Answer (score -2):

```
List < Integer > odd = new ArrayList < Integer > ();

List < Integer > even = new ArrayList < Integer > ();

int a [] = {0,2,3,98,1,6546,45323,1134564};

int i;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

    if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {

        even.add(a[i]);

    } else {

        odd.add(a[i]);

    }
}

System.out.print("Even: " + even + "\n");
System.out.print("Uneven: " + odd + "\n");
}
}
```

Comment: This seems to be essentially identical to the answers from over half a decade ago--can you explain in your answer what additional benefit it brings over previous answers? See also the comment on the other code-only answer.