# Divide array in two parts

Tags: java, arrays

> I have an Array[10] divide my array into two different array A and B.
>   A having element of Array which were on even indices and B has
>   elements of Array of odd indices.
>
> Respond fast with appropriate code using for loop.

Comment: I would like to get my array divided into two arrays of equal size

Comment: -1 for not trying it on your own first, -infinity (negative infinity) for `Respond fast with appropriate code using for loop.` (We are not your employees, and even my bosses don't give me orders like that.)

Comment: Just go to this site: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages and tell us on which language you need this

Comment: try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930884/array-even-odd-sorting

Answer (score 2):

```java
class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    // Creating arrays
    int array[], a[], b[];
    array = new int[10];
    a = new int[5];
    b = new int[5];

    // Giving initial values to array, and printing
    System.out.print("array: " );
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      array[i] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
      System.out.print("\t" + array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();


    // Splitting the array in two
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      a[i] = array[2 * i];
      b[i] = array[2 * i + 1];
    }

    // Printing a
    System.out.print("a : " );
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      System.out.print("\t" + a[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Printing b
    System.out.print("b : " );
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      System.out.print("\t" + b[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
array:  8   8   6   0   4   0   0   9   9   2
a :     8   6   4   0   9
b :     8   0   0   9   2
```